# How to correctly type indexed global object

Tags: typescript

I'm currently experimenting with converting a large monolithic JavaScript application to TypeScript. I'm having problems with how to correctly type a particular module and I wondered if anyone knows how to do it.

Please note that **the original code was not written by me - I am simply trying to convert an existing application, so if there is anything wrong with the JavaScript, telling me that isn't going to be useful**

Here is the original code for the module (thankfully its quite small).

```
const CACHE_CONTROL_HEADERS = Symbol.for('cache control headers')

if (!global[CACHE_CONTROL_HEADERS]) {
  global[CACHE_CONTROL_HEADERS] = [];
}

module.exports = global[CACHE_CONTROL_HEADERS];
```

Now I've established that TypeScript [does not support using symbols as index signatures](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1863), so I know I need to cast the first line. I also believe I need to change the last line to ES6 module format, so that leaves me with this:

```
const CACHE_CONTROL_HEADERS = (Symbol.for(
  "cache control headers"
) as unknown) as string;

if (!global[CACHE_CONTROL_HEADERS]) {
  global[CACHE_CONTROL_HEADERS] = [];
}

export default global[CACHE_CONTROL_HEADERS];
```

This now leaves me with the following compile error:

```
index.ts:6:3 - error TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Global & typeof globalThis'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Global & typeof globalThis'.
```

Now after a bit of googling, I've found various approaches to augmenting the type of the global object, and I've attempted to put the following into a file alongside the module file:

```
declare module NodeJS {
  interface Global {
    [key: string]: string;
  }
}
```

This unfortunately doesn't change the error, and my editor also throws up some other errors on the index signature, e.g.

```
Property 'Array' of type 'ArrayConstructor' is not assignable to string index type 'string[]'
```

At this point, I'm truly stuck. If anyone can help me turn this tiny file into TypeScript, I'd be more than grateful!

Comment: do you really want an index signature (any symbol) or would it also be okay if it is just *that* symbol? because that totally works

Comment: Ultimately I just want the code to compile without changing the underlying logic...

Comment: I'm not quite sure I follow what you mean though

Comment: you say that `TS does not support using symbols as index signatures`, but you do not need an index signature to add *one extra property*. An index signature would be for *all strings* or *all numbers* or *all symbols* and I doubt you want that

Answer (score 3):

No pretty, but you could cast every usage of `global` to a custom type, that extends the original `typeof global`:

```
type CacheControlGlobal = typeof global & {
  [CACHE_CONTROL_HEADERS]: string[];
};

(global as CacheControlGlobal)[CACHE_CONTROL_HEADERS] = [];
```

Here's [the complete playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAwgQTgCQKIH04HkByAVAJSwBl00EARVAgZRgF4YaBPAWwCMQAbAOgDMQAJwAUAcmABDYAAsApjFBgog7jDkSAJrMERRASgDcAKCNRmAB3lwpcuOGXcA4lxDsJXBjDOWQfGAHMXNw8AMhgAbyMYGABtRBQMbHwiUnIqWgBdAC4YaEEASzB-GIzjAF9jI3y-YQBCYUDXdxgJCHgbWTslFS5nJq49OKQ0TFxCEjJUSmoaDL0IqJgGoObW9plO%20x6%204MH4kaTx1Kn02c8S8pNZAA9zIVgtPgkAVy5YYWX%20lrbnsABrMAgADuYHma2sGy6Dl6KwGQwSo2SEzSM1KRiAA) (caveat that `global` doesn't work, please copy to a local environment).

Extending the existing type will not only make the code work, but also allows you to keep other typed features working, like auto-completion. The types are also similar enough that you don't have to cast via `unknown`, which helps with readability.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need an index signature for one extra property - and you can use symbols as properties just fine:

For Window:

```
export {}
declare global {
  interface Window {
    [CACHE_CONTROL_HEADERS]: WhatEverTypeYouWantThisToHave;
  }
}

const CACHE_CONTROL_HEADERS = Symbol.for("foo")
interface WhatEverTypeYouWantThisToHave {
  x: ""
}

window[CACHE_CONTROL_HEADERS].x //works
```

And for Global:

```
export {};

interface WhatEverTypeYouWantThisToHave {
  x: string;
}

declare global {
  module NodeJS {
    interface Global {
      [CACHE_CONTROL_HEADERS]: WhatEverTypeYouWantThisToHave;
    }
  }
}

const CACHE_CONTROL_HEADERS = Symbol.for("foo");

const x: string = global[CACHE_CONTROL_HEADERS].x;

// let's provoke another error to prove this file is parsed
const y: number = global[CACHE_CONTROL_HEADERS].x;
```

Comment: This does not work. I get almost the same error:

`index.ts:9:6 - error TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'unique symbol' can't be used to index type 'Global & typeof globalThis'.
  Property '[CACHE_CONTROL_HEADERS]' does not exist on type 'Global & typeof globalThis'.`

Comment: I'm not sure how your edit helps me at all. I don't need to extend `Window`, I need to extend global. Your solution doesn't work. Here is a playground https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAEwpgxgNghgTmABAWwPYgK5SQOXWAKQGVEBvYRRASwDsAXMOAMxgiQHEpUAjGKMipUQBtAMIBBUQAkAogH1RAeRwAVAEqKAMnNniAIjLVEAugC5EAZzpxaAc0EBfYE+ARUNK4gnT5S1Ru1dAyNEAF5EIgBPZG5UKAA6JlQ4AAoAcghWAAskN3o4OMQcmHA4CzSASmBgKiZEFIBCWy5eKDFJWQVldS0dGX1DEwqBSmaePnafLv9eoMHjMJFjAG5narAADwAHZLpEcBYsPbHWyc6-HsD+4JNloA

Comment: You'll need to install it locally to get the same errors because the playground doesn't have @types/node

Comment: that's really not that different. see edit.

Comment: Yes. But it _doesn't work_. Even with *identical* code to your third edit (ie, I delete my code, and paste yours in), I'm still getting the same compile error described in my first comment.

Comment: I have tested this locally, it works. Something must be wrong in your setup.

Comment: Ok. I've created a minimal reproduction repository: https://github.com/benwainwright/minimalIssue - test.ts contains the exact code of your third example. If I do a fresh clone of this repository and then run `yarn && yarn tsc`, I get a compile error.

Comment: I think you are probably testing with `noImplicitAny` turned off. That's not an option for me.

Comment: I was testing with `strict: true` and `global[CACHE_CONTROL_HEADERS].x` was explicitly typed  as `string` on hover

Comment: see https://gist.github.com/phryneas/a9689e0356f38ed68da79e1885c2bb55

Comment: did you try my minimal repro?

Comment: now I did. if you copy the code from my gist over it works. no idea what's different now.

Comment: the difference was in your gist you put "declare global { module NodeJS { interface Global", which is slightly different to the way you did it in your edit. That works. If you edit your answer I'll accept it :) thanks for your help.